# Reading single line CSV with multiple sections

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io

I have data from a file that is arranged like so:

`[{"start": "2014-02-24T00:48:57", "stop": "2014-02-24T07:30:53", "events": [[60.0, 1, 0.015800000000000002],...,[28500.0, 3,
0.034299999999999997]]}]`

where the '...' symbolizes repeating data in the form `[x, y, z]` separated by commas

x appears to be a float; y is always 1, 2, or 3; z appears to be a double

The data is a .txt file and all this data is contained on one line. I am getting this data from a third party source so I cannot get it in any other format.

I want to be able to read the start and stop sections separately, and then read all of the events section into arrays.

`Ex. x = 60.0 ... 28500.0; y = 1 ... 3; z = 0.015800000000000002 ... 0.034299999999999997`

I have an idea on how to read the first sections, but I'm not sure on how to handle the brackets, and braces.

I imagine I could read in 3 values: `start`, `stop`, and `events` and then parse events from there. But I still am a bit confused. I am not looking for an exact answer necessarily, just how to go about doing it.

This data is obtained from the `SleepCycle` app I use on an `iPhone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse it as JSON => you now have an array with a single element in it. That element is an object with start, stop, and events attributes.

I think the specifics depend mostly on what language you're using and what json parsing libraries are available.

Comment: Good call. There would appear to be [plenty of JSON parsers for Matlab](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=JSON&term=JSON).

Comment: The name of the file is data_json.txt. I had no idea that it referred to the formatting of data. Thank you.